# Cannot POST / angular routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post, request, browserify

I've searched and can't quite find someone with the same circumstances, I'm using angular routing to perform CRUD on a mock db.json server and when I execute the 'update' function, it changes the value in the database, but always redirects me to a blank page that just says 'Cannot POST /'. Even though the request actually went through. I'd just like it to return to the /clients page once the request is finished. I'm using browserify to include angular and angular-route. Thanks in advance :)

```
// Router 
  var UNRealtyApp = angular.module('UNRealtyApp', ['ngRoute'])

    UNRealtyApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/clients', {templateUrl: 'app/views/clients.html', controller: 'clientListCtrl'})
        .when('/add-client', {templateUrl: 'app/views/client-add.html', controller: 'clientAddCtrl'})
        .when('/edit-client/:id', {templateUrl: 'app/views/client-edit.html', controller: 'clientEditCtrl'})
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/404'});
  }]);

//Client CRUD 
      UNRealtyApp.controller('clientListCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
        console.log('clientListCtrl activated')
        $http.get('http://localhost:3000/clients/').success(function(data) {
          $scope.clients = data;
        })
      }) 

      UNRealtyApp.controller('clientAddCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location){
        console.log('clientAddCtrl activated')
        $scope.master = {};
        $scope.activePath = null;

        $scope.add_new = function(client, AddNewForm) {
          console.log('add_new activated')
          $http.post('http://localhost:3000/clients/', client).success(function(){
            $scope.reset();
            $scope.activePath = $location.path('/clients');
          });

          $scope.reset = function() {
            console.log('reset activated')
            $scope.client = angular.copy($scope.master);
          };
          $scope.reset();
        }
      })

      UNRealtyApp.controller('clientEditCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams){
        console.log('clientEditCtrl activated')
        var id = $routeParams.id;
        // $scope.activePath = null;
        $http.get('http://localhost:3000/clients/' + id).success(function(data) {
          $scope.clients = [data];
        });

        $scope.update = function(client){
          console.log('update activated')
          $http.put('http://localhost:3000/clients/' + id, client).success(function(data) {
            $scope.clients = data;
            $scope.activePath = $location.path('clients');
          });
        };

        $scope.delete = function(client) {
          console.log('delete activated')
          var deleteClient = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');
          if (deleteClient) {
            $http.delete('http://localhost:3000/clients/' + client.id);
            $scope.activePath = $location.path('clients');
          }
        }
      })
```

Comment: have you tried changing `.success` to `.then` on your `POST` request

Comment: Not sure if this would be correct, but have you tried changing your route "/clients" to something different? I wonder if the post request is conflicting with your route settings.